# (Array PHP) The shortest way to plus two arrays

Tags: php

I assume that I have two array like:

```
$arr1 = array('a' => 1,'b',null,1);
$arr2 = array('c', 'a' => 2, array());
```

I want to:

```
$arr1 + $arr2 = array(array('a'=>1),'b',null,1,'c', array('a'=>2), array());
$arr2 + $arr1 =  array('c', array('a'=>2), array(),array('a'=>1),'b',null,1);
```

which functions help me do these above things. Thanks.

See my edit.

Comment: I mean plus two arrays. Not merge. see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Use `array_merge`

```
$arr12 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
$arr21 = array_merge($arr2, $arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array_merge()` function will do that for you:

```
$arr1 = array('a','b',null,1);
$arr2 = array('c', 'a', array());


print_r(array_merge($arr1,$arr2));

print_r(array_merge($arr2,$arr1));
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one.

Example

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Example from [Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

In your case use

```
$result1 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$result2 = array_merge($array2, $array1);
```